# Unable to Resize Partition (GParted/Mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gparted

I am trying to resize a partition to install another flavour of Linux (Arch). But somehow I am unable to resize the main partition into two. I have attached an image of my drive setup now. Can you please let me know what am I supposed to do there. The Move/Resize window has everything greyed out.

[image]

Its the /dev/sda3 partition that I want to split right down the middle into two.

Comment: Little key icons say partitions are mounted. You cannot change mounted partitions. You have to use live installer. But you also have LVM which cannot be changed with gparted, but you have to use LVM tools for the volumes. Maybe better then to have another volume inside existing one for new install rather than shrinking volume and then shrinking partition.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: Can you please add the output of `lsblk /dev/sda` and `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? The bad news is that resizing the partition is hard. The good news is that you could relatively easily only resize a logical volume, create a new one, and install your second OS there. If you are OK with tho OSes sharing the same encrypted volume.

Comment: Would reinstalling Mint, without the drive encryption this time solve the problem? I only installed it 4 days ago and don't anything significant to backup?

Comment: If reinstalling is an option, implying that you are fine with losing everything on that device, then yes, it will work, and won't even need to give up on encryption. I don't know the Mint installer, but you should be able to customize partitioning and leave room for a second OS (e.g. create a partition of about half the disk size and install Mint there).